# How to Generate Several inline dd for one dt in Bootstrap Description

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Can you please let me know how I can have several inline dd for one dt?

Foe Example a code like this :

```
<dl>
 <dt>Acura</dt>
 <dd>RDX</dd>
 <dd>MDX</dd>
 <dd>ZDX</dd>
</dl>
```

will display like:

[image]

but I would like to render thr dd(s) as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this CSS to `display` the items `inline`

```
dl dd{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Schmalzy, I wish I knw how you learn bootstrap so well!

Comment: No prob. This isn't actually bootstrap at all, its just basic CSS.